# MySQL, stored procedure, discrepancy setting local variable

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in MySQL (5.7.22)

I have a declared local variable.

My understanding is that I can set it several ways, including 'SET' and 'SELECT INTO'.

`SET` produces the results I expect, it sets the local variable, in this case to NULL which triggers the exit handler.

`SELECT INTO` does not produce the result I expect. It does not seem to set it to NULL, so the exit handler is never signaled.

What is really odd to me is that the final `SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'` is not even triggered in Example 2.

What am I missing?

Thanks

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `test_proc`(IN p_id INT)
BEGIN
  DECLARE v_var INT DEFAULT NULL;

  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION, SQLWARNING
  BEGIN
   RESIGNAL;
  END;

  /* Example 1 - works as expected */
  SET v_var := (SELECT `id` FROM our_table WHERE `id` = p_id);

  /* this is triggered */
  IF(v_var IS NULL) THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
      SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Not found';
  END IF;


   -- comment out above to run example 2

  /* Example 2 - Does not work as expected */
  SELECT `id` INTO v_var FROM our_table WHERE `id`=p_id;

  /* this is not triggered */
  IF(v_var IS NULL) THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
      SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Not found';
  END IF;

  /* in fact - this is not triggered either... */
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Not found';


END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this statement:

```
SELECT id INTO v_var
FROM our_table
WHERE id = p_id;
```

This loops through `our_table`.  When it finds a match, *then* the `SELECT` clause is invoked and the value is placed in the variable.  Alas.  No match, no invocation of `SELECT` -- and no assignment.

The `SET` is a different story:

```
SET v_var = (SELECT `id` FROM our_table WHERE `id` = p_id);
```

(Note that `:=` is not needed for `SET`.)  This is using a *scalar subquery*.  A scalar subquery always returns a value.  If the subquery returns one row, then that is the value.  If the subquery returns no rows, then the value is `NULL`.  So, `NULL` is assigned in this case.

In other words, no assignment at all *is not the same as* assignment to `NULL`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, this was not clear to me based on the docs. I thought they were equivalent. So it seems there is no way of doing a multiple variable assigns in one query then checking those variables for NULL.

Comment: Just an update, I came up with a solution, based on the docs "This condition also occurs for SELECT ... INTO var_list statements that retrieve no rows." I was able to declare a handler for 'NOT FOUND' in separate BEGIN/END blocks.